# Can't see login page after migration

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, migration, localhost

I already have an existing website on live server. I want to setup on local machine.

Following Steps has been taken:

1. Download whole website
2. Place whole code under `htdocs/mywp`
3. Change the database file. replace all link from `https://www.example.com` to `http://10.1.15.5/mywp` (my local IP)
4. Import the database and change the `wp-config` file
5. Deleted .htaccess file

Now, when I visit: `http://10.1.15.5/mywp`

The page load except for the styling (CSS). When I try to visit: `http://10.1.15.5/mywp/wp-admin` It doesn't  open 
it redirects to:

`https://10.1.5.15/mywp/yourwp/login/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2F10.1.5.15%2Fmywp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

Can anybody tell me what steps can be taken?

Comment: Looks like you have file/folder permission issue. Please check that. Anyways what does the console says

Comment: @AnkitaKashyap Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are still having content pointing back to your live URL, possibly. To ensure that you have changed all the URLs from `https://www.example.com` to `http://10.1.15.5/mywp`, follow these steps:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://10.1.15.5/mywp/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your old URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plug in https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ for database migration and URL replacement and check all files are properly  uploaded to new site

Comment: We can't use any plugin on live site.. if i am on local  cant able to lgin how do i install